# Enable taxonomies by post type in an array of CPTs

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, taxonomy

I learnt to add multiple custom post types via `functions.php` in an array, like this:

```
add_action('init', 'all_custom_post_types');

function all_custom_post_types() {
  $types = array(
        array('the_type' => 'event',
            'single' => 'Event',
            'plural' => 'Events'
        ),
        array('the_type' => 'resource',
            'single' => 'Resource',
            'plural' => 'Resources'
        ),
        array('the_type' => 'team',
            'single' => 'Team',
            'plural' => 'Team'
        ),
  );
```

All well and good, and the options for these post types can be declared as follows:

```
  foreach ($types as $type) {
    $the_type = $type['the_type'];
    $single = $type['single'];
    $plural = $type['plural'];
    $labels = array(
      'name' => _x($plural, 'post type general name'),
      'singular_name' => _x($single, 'post type singular name'),
      'add_new' => _x('Add New', $single),
      'add_new_item' => __('Add New '. $single),
      'edit_item' => __('Edit '.$single),
      'new_item' => __('New '.$single),
      'view_item' => __('View '.$single),
      'search_items' => __('Search '.$plural),
      'not_found' =>  __('No '.$plural.' found'),
      'not_found_in_trash' => __('No '.$plural.' found in Trash'),
      'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );
    $args = array(
      'labels' => $labels,
      'public' => true,
      'publicly_queryable' => true,
      'show_ui' => true,
      'query_var' => true,
      'rewrite'  => array( 
         'with_front' => false
      ),
      'capability_type' => 'post',
      'hierarchical' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'menu_position' => 5,
      'supports' => array('title','editor','author'),
      'show_in_menu' => true,
      'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
      'taxonomies' => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
    );
    register_post_type($the_type, $args);
  }
}
```

But what if I want the `taxonomies => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),` line to apply to the `resource` post type only? In this instance I'd like to enable taxonomies as follows:

- `resource`: categories AND tags
- `event`: tags ONLY
- `team`: no taxonomy terms

Can this be done the way I've declared my custom post types, or should I be declaring them separately to achieve more granular control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tweaked theyour code and it should work.. please give it a try

```
add_action('init', 'all_custom_post_types');

function all_custom_post_types() {
  $types = array(
        array('the_type' => 'event',
            'single' => 'Event',
            'plural' => 'Events'
        ),
        array('the_type' => 'resource',
            'single' => 'Resource',
            'plural' => 'Resources'
        ),
        array('the_type' => 'team',
            'single' => 'Team',
            'plural' => 'Team'
        ),
  );
foreach ($types as $type) {
    $the_type = $type['the_type'];
    $single = $type['single'];
    $plural = $type['plural'];
    $labels = array(
      'name' => _x($plural, 'post type general name'),
      'singular_name' => _x($single, 'post type singular name'),
      'add_new' => _x('Add New', $single),
      'add_new_item' => __('Add New '. $single),
      'edit_item' => __('Edit '.$single),
      'new_item' => __('New '.$single),
      'view_item' => __('View '.$single),
      'search_items' => __('Search '.$plural),
      'not_found' =>  __('No '.$plural.' found'),
      'not_found_in_trash' => __('No '.$plural.' found in Trash'),
      'parent_item_colon' => ''
    );
    $args = array(
      'labels' => $labels,
      'public' => true,
      'publicly_queryable' => true,
      'show_ui' => true,
      'query_var' => true,
      'rewrite'  => array( 
         'with_front' => false
      ),
      'capability_type' => 'post',
      'hierarchical' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'menu_position' => 5,
      'supports' => array('title','editor','author'),
      'show_in_menu' => true,
      'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
    );

    if($the_type=='resource'){
        $args['taxonomies'] = array( 'category', 'post_tag' );
    }elseif($the_type=="event"){
        $args['taxonomies'] = array( 'post_tag' );
    }else{
    }
    register_post_type($the_type, $args);
  }
}
```

Comment: ah yes – this removes cats and tags from all CPTs but `resource`, thanks. as per my question i was looking to allow tags only on the `event` CPT as well. i figured that appending an `elseif ($the_type=="event"){$args['taxonomies'] = array( 'post_tag' );}` would have made that happen, but no?

Comment: hey @mtm , glad you figured it out. Though I modified my answer too for your exact case. If this helped you , it will be great i you can accept the answer or vote up atleast.

Comment: thanks – thing is, that's not working. i've just updated with your tweak too but the same problem persists. no tags on `event` post type. any ideas?

Comment: I tweaked the code again and above code is working perfect for me

Comment: yes that's working now but for some reason the 'tags' menu item isn't present under 'events' in the admin menu, although both taxonomy items are present for resources. do you have any idea why/how to fix?

Comment: my bad – this was an unrelated setting at my end. thanks so much!

Comment: glad you figured it out